# How to take picture using hidden camera?

Tags: coronasdk

In my application i have to take picture from camera.but i need camera view in hidden.if its possible to take picture without calling camera mode or if any possible to overlap the camera view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corona uses a native camera/media library method to access the camera and does not provide direct access to the camera.  So this is not possible that I'm aware of.